# Change Case Owner and Live Agent

Tags: case, liveagent

Is there a way to change the case owner to the person who is accepting the chat in live agent.

The scenario is that the user raises a case and then he gets an option to chat with support.  The case is automatically sent to the support queue and by the time the representative is talking to the customer, someone else picks up the case and starts working on it.

Is there a way to automatically assign the case to the representative who picks up / accepts the chat?

Answer (score 1):

Create a process builder with the criteria:

1. `Livetranscript.caseid doesnotequals Null AND LivechatTranscript.OwnerId ischanged boolean false` and under Actions select Action Type as Update a Record. Select related record as `caseId`, select the action as `OwnerId`, Formula as `$User.Id`.
2. Criteria as `liveChattranscript.CaseId doesnotequals Null AND liveChatTranscript.OwnerId doesnotequals formula liveChatTranscript.Case.OwnerId`.
   Select related record as `caseId`, select the action as `Ownerid`, Formula as 
   `liveChatTranscript.OwnerId`.

Don't forget to choose stop and select evaluate next criteria for 1 condition.

Comment: It would not work until Live Chat Transcript gets created...but gotcha is that Live chat transcript is created after end of Chat.. but use case is owner should get updated when Chat starts not when chat ends!